# How to delete all lines of a text file that contain ./

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have text files with data that looks like this

| chrom | start | end | gene | mutation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chr1 | 12756 | 12790 | DVL1 | T/C |
| chr1 | 12856 | 12890 | DVL2 | ./. |
| chr1 | 12956 | 12990 | DVL3 | T/C |

I need to delete all the lines that contain ./. in them, the files are around 500 lines so I don't need anything super efficient.

I've tried a bunch of different approaches with no success, both to cut out the "./." and to cut out the lines that don't contain "./." in the final column.

```
grep -v "./." input.txt > output.txt

awk '/"./."/' input.txt > tmpfile && mv tmpfile output.txt

fgrep -xv "./." input.txt > output.txt

awk -F',' '$5 !~ "./." {print $0}' input.txt > output.txt

awk 'BEGIN { OFS=FS="\t" } $5 !~ /^('./.')/' input.txt > output.txt

awk '!"./." ' input.txt > output.txt

sed -i '"./."d' input.txt > output.txt
```

I feel like I'm close but just can't see what i'm missing, any help is appreciated.

Comment: `grep -v '\./\.'`, escape the dots. Or use `grep -vF './.' `. See https://ideone.com/IcjM5Z

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, OP is looking to ignore those lines, dupe given here is finding the lines with dots IMHO.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 The only issue about escaping special char, a dot. Or using the `-F` option. Everything is covered in that post. In general, a dupe of [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions), but I tried to find a `grep`-oriented post here

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I agree somewhat few things are covered, but when we have a full fledge answer then why to go for partial dupe. I am fine if we put a exact dupe to make this dupe.

Comment: @kellogg76, with `awk`, you can use string comparison instead of regex `'$NF != "./."'`

Comment: This `both to cut out the "./." and to cut out the lines that don't contain "./." in the final column` means don't print the line if there is `./.` in it right? Regardless of it being in the last column, and the result should be the 1st and the 3rd line?

Comment: With your artistic rendering of what the input text looks like, we can't tell which of these is correct. `awk -F ','` would work if the input is comma-separated; `awk -F '\t'` would be correct if it's tab-separated. Either of those should have worked if you had used a correct regex, but we can't tell without further details.

Comment: You showed us all the things you tried, but you didn't explain what didn't work.

Comment: [edit] your question to show concise, testable, plain-text sample input and expected output so we can help you. No images, no links, no artistic tables, just raw text that we can copy/paste as-is to test a potential solution with.

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple `grep`, simply use `-v` option to ignore given pattern lines.

```
grep -v '\./\.' Input_file
```

OR in `awk` try following:

```
awk '$NF=="./."{next} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't tell from your input data what your input file looks like. If it's tab-delimited, tell Awk to split on a tab:

```sh
awk -F '\t' '$5 != "./."' input.txt >output.txt
```

If you have a comma-delimited input file, the corresponding command would look like

```sh
awk -F ',' '$5 != "./."' input.txt >output.txt
```

The `!=` string inequivalence operator is simpler to use than a regular expression here.  We are simply saying "print lines where the fifth column is not exactly this string."

The corresponding regex would look like

```sh
awk -F ',' '$5 !~ /^\.\/\.$/' input.txt >output.txt
```

but you would obviously like to avoid the [leaning toothpicks syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome) here.

In some more detail,

- `grep -v "./."` is wrong because it removes any line with a slash with any character at all on either side. You can fix this by escaping the dots with a backslash or character class; `grep -v '\./[.]'` demonstrates both. This is still wrong in that it looks for the pattern anywhere, not just in the last field; but if you don't expect matches in other fields, maybe that's good enough.
- `awk '/"./."/'` looks for a slash surrounded by literal double quotes on both sides, with any character in between.
- `fgrep -xv "./."` is otherwise good, but the `-x` option limits the expression to only match lines which contain nothing else than the pattern.
- `awk -F',' '$5 !~ "./." {print $0}'` would work for a comma-delimited file if you fix the regex. The `{ print $0 }` is redundant but harmless.
- `awk 'BEGIN { OFS=FS="\t" } $5 !~ /^('./.')/'` holds some promise for tab-delimited files, but the regex is hopelessly botched. The single quotes inside the regex are wrong, but will happily not break the syntax of the script; they will basically disappear before Awk processes the script because quotes are handled by the shell ... Long story short, read up on shell quoting.
- `awk '!"./." '` will not do anything; it says to print if the static string in the condition is empty, which it isn't.
- `sed -i '"./."d' input.txt > output.txt` is wrong because the `-i` option will make changes to `input.txt` and not print anything to standard output; the regex is flawed both because of the quoting problems and because it needs to be surrounded by valid regex delimiters. `sed '/\.\/\./d' input.txt > output.txt` would work similarly to the first `grep` example above.